# Change number of items per page or view all in a view using a paginator in django

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-views

I am using django 1.3 and I have a view that takes a paginated queryset (set to use 50 objects). Here is the relevant part of the get_context_data() method in the view:

```
    #build paginator for querysets
    paginated_scanned_assets = Paginator(scanned_assets_qs, 50)

    #get the specified page
    try:
        page_num = int(self.request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page_num = 1

    #get a paginated list of object
    try:
        scanned_assets = paginated_scanned_assets.page(page_num)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        scanned_assets = paginated_scanned_assets.page(paginated_scanned_assets.num_pages)
```

The template it renders to just builds a table from the queryset and has links to go to the next and previous pages.

What I want to do is either have a link to view all, which would just display the queryset unpaginated, or an option to modify the number of objects per page (which would recreate the paginator). I haven't worked with views or design much though so I am not sure how to do this. Is it something I can do with js, and if so how? Otherwise can I just do it with django and html? It might be really simple, I am just pretty inexperienced and haven't found an answer or example anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is add an optional parameter to the view called 'page_size' and then do something like:

```
def your_view(request, ..., page_size=50):
  scanned_assets_qs = # get your scanned_assets QuerySet

  if page_size == -1:
    page_size = scanned_assets_qs.count()

  paginator = Paginator(scanned_assets_qs, page_size)
```

Then you can pass in an arbitrary page_size, and a -1 for a view all page (I would do that with the appropriate urls, plus a url for /viewall/ that passes in -1 no matter what)